# Why CSR format outperforms CSC format in selecting rows?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am doing this little experiment on CSR and CSC format based on `scipy.sparse`. As [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix) claims, CSC format are more efficient than CSR format when dealing with column operations. So I did this small experiment:

```py
from scipy.sparse import diags
d = diags([-1, 1, 1], [-1, 0, -1], shape= (100, 100))
%timeit d.tocsc()[:, 1]
%timeit d.tocsr()[:, 1]
```

Then I suppose I got the row and column in the wrong way. So I tried the other way around:

```py
%timeit d.tocsc()[1]
%timeit d.tocsr()[1]
```

But in cases CSR outperforms CSC in timing. I was wondering if there is any structural reason for such results, or are my tests just biased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing of sparse matrices is complicated, with a number of variables that could affect times. Your test case is symmetric, so `csr` and `csc` formats will be nearly the same.  Things could be different if the shape is rectangular, or the layout different.

Also indexing with a scalar versus a slice versus a list may be different.

Keep in mind that sparse indexing, regardless of format, is much slower than `numpy.ndarray`.  Try not to use sparse if you need to iterate. (And if you must iterate, consider working with the 'raw' sparse attributes directly.)

```
In [64]: d = sparse.diags([-1, 1, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape= (100, 100))                 
In [65]: d                                                                           
Out[65]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 298 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>

In [66]: %timeit d.tocsr()[:,1]                                                      
422 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [67]: %timeit d.tocsc()[:,1]                                                      
506 µs ± 5.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [68]: %timeit d.tocsc()[1,:]                                                      
506 µs ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Separate the conversion from the indexing:

```
In [69]: %%timeit x=d.tocsr() 
    ...: x[:,1]                                                                              
121 µs ± 2.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [70]: %%timeit x=d.tocsr() 
    ...: x[1,:]                                                                           
118 µs ± 2.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [71]: %%timeit x=d.tocsc() 
    ...: x[:,1]                                                                            
290 µs ± 5.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [72]: %%timeit x=d.tocsc() 
    ...: x[1,:]                                                                            
297 µs ± 14.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I'm a little surprised that the `csr` times are consistently faster.  But just a little.  `csc` and `csr` use a common `compressed` base class (`sparse.compressed._cs_matrix`), but coding details seem to favor `csr`.

===

And just for the fun of it, index a `lil` format

```
In [73]: %%timeit x=d.tolil() 
    ...: x[1,:]                                                                            
76.4 µs ± 231 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [74]: %%timeit x=d.tolil() 
    ...: x[:,1]                                                                       
118 µs ± 647 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As expected from the `lil` storage, row indexing is faster, though the column index time isn't bad.

`lil` has a `getrow` which is the closest thing in `sparse` to a `numpy` view:

```
In [75]: %%timeit x=d.tolil() 
    ...: x.getrow(1)                                                                          
36.7 µs ± 233 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

===

Dense array indexing, even with conversion time is faster:

```
In [83]: %%timeit x=d.A 
    ...: x[:,1]                                                                          
277 ns ± 9.97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [84]: timeit d.A[:,1]                                                             
197 µs ± 587 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks that's really informative!! Two follow-up Qs: Somehow when i tested on my laptop `tolil` is the slowest among three? and so if my task were to handle a huge diagonal banded matrix in a long loop, should I sacrifice my memory storage for efficiency? (in your opinion)